# OpenSSL: Promote insecure BIO to secure one

Tags: c++, ssl, ftp, openssl, ftps

I'm trying to create a simple FTP/FTPS client implementation in C++ using OpenSSL. I've managed it to work with plain FTP using BIO API. Now the question is: once I have an insecure connection and BIO object, how can I upgrade the connection to use encryption? The connection works in plain FTP until `AUTH TLS` command is sent, and at that point TLS/SSL session should be negotiated. There is the `BIO_new_ssl_connect` function, but AFAIK, instead of reusing the existing connection, it creates a new connection.

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [`BIO_new_ssl_connect` source code](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0g/ssl/bio_ssl.c#L464):

```
BIO *BIO_new_ssl_connect(SSL_CTX *ctx)
{
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_SOCK
    BIO *ret = NULL, *con = NULL, *ssl = NULL;

    if ((con = BIO_new(BIO_s_connect())) == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    if ((ssl = BIO_new_ssl(ctx, 1)) == NULL)
        goto err;
    if ((ret = BIO_push(ssl, con)) == NULL)
        goto err;
    return (ret);
 err:
    BIO_free(con);
#endif
    return (NULL);
}
```

And do the same, just skip the `BIO_s_connect`.

Comment: Using this advice, I was able to get it to work. Thanks!